# Static variable in template function fail

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, static-variables

Header file (test.h):

```
#ifndef _test_h_
#define _test_h_

#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>

typedef std::map<int, std::string> MIS;

//-----1-----
template<typename T> const std::pair<int, std::string> mkpair1(T t)
{
    static int i=0;
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << t;
    return std::pair<int, std::string>(++i, ss.str());
}

template<typename...Any> void mkmap1(MIS &m, Any...any)
{
    m = { mkpair1(any)... };
};

//-----2-----
template<typename T> const std::pair<int, std::string> mkpair2(int i, T t)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << t;
    return std::pair<int, std::string>(i, ss.str());
}

template<typename...Any> void mkmap2(MIS &m, Any...any)
{
    static int i=0;
    m = { mkpair2(++i, any)... };
};

//-----3-----
template<typename T> const std::pair<int, std::string> mkpair3(int &i, T t)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << t;
    return std::pair<int, std::string>(++i, ss.str());
}

template<typename...Any> void mkmap3(MIS &m, Any...any)
{
    int i=0;
    m = { mkpair3(i, any)... };
};

#endif
```

Program file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "test.h"

void ShowM(int x, const MIS &m)
{
    std::cout << "\n---" << x << "---\n";
    for (auto p:m) std::cout << p.first << " -> " << p.second << "\n";
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    MIS m;

    m.clear();
    mkmap1(m, 1, "two", 3.1415, "four", 5);
    ShowM(1, m);

    m.clear();
    mkmap2(m, 1, "two", 3.1415, "four", 5);
    ShowM(2, m);

    m.clear();
    mkmap3(m, 1, "two", 3.1415, "four", 5);
    ShowM(3, m);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
---1---
1 -> 1
2 -> four

---2---
1 -> 1
2 -> two
3 -> 3.1415
4 -> four
5 -> 5

---3---
1 -> 1
2 -> two
3 -> 3.1415
4 -> four
5 -> 5
```

Why does the first template functions fail to build the map correctly? The result is strange. (Using gcc on Linux)

Edit:

Following on '101010' neat explanation, from [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/insert/):

> Because element keys in a map are unique, the insertion operation
>   checks whether each inserted element has a key equivalent to the one
>   of an element already in the container, and if so, the element is not
>   inserted, returning an iterator to this existing element (if the
>   function returns a value).

Comment: Short answer: mkpair<int> and mkpair<const char *> are separate functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As correctly [@immibis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106104/immibis) mentioned in the comments, due to template argument deduction there are 3 template instantiations of template function `mkpair1` generated, namely:

```
mkpair1<int>(...) // for inputs 1, 5
mkpair1<double>(...) // for input 3.1415
mkpair1<const char*>(...) // for input "tow" and "four"
```

Consequently, the variadic template expansion would look something like:

```
m = { mkpair1<int>(1), 
      mkpair1<const char*>("two"),
      mkpair1<double>(3.1415),
      mkpair1<const char*>("four"),
      mkpair1<int>(5)
    };
```

Now due to the fact that for each template instantiation generated you have a different `static int i` defined as well, you would have the following insertion scheme:

```
m.insert(std::make_pair(1, "1");      // OK
m.insert(std::make_pair(1, "two");    // ignored due to key 1 already exists
m.insert(std::make_pair(1, "3.1415"); // ignored due to key 1 already exists
m.insert(std::make_pair(2, "four");   // OK
m.insert(std::make_pair(2, "5"));     // ignored due to key 2 already exists
```

Thus rightfully, you get the result:

```
---1---
1 -> 1
2 -> four
```

Comment: Ah, thx. wood-for-the-trees-again; the code works correctly and it is map::insert that derailed me.